# Read a text file to a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, file

I have a file that I want to read into a variable in JS to use it later

```
var states;
$.get('states.json', function(data) {
        states=data;
        alert(data);
        alert(states);
    }, "text");

 alert(states);
```

In the above code, value of `states` is that of the file inside the function, but it is null outside.

Comment: You need to understand how asynchronous calls work in javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `alert` at the end runs **before** the file is received. Ajax is *asynchronous* by default.

Comment: OK so my code should wait till the file is completely fetched before proceeding further.
`var states;
$.get('states.json', function(data) {
        states=data;
        alert(data);
        alert(states);
    }, "text");

 //alert(states);


var Cstates = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {                //combo box data
        fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
        data: states
    });
 `
this is the code later in the file, can i hold it till the value is fetched into the variable??

Comment: @user2612159: The point is to call whatever code you need to use the data with from within the callback, because that's when you know it's there and ready. You can't stop the execution and wait for it (or you could look at it that that's *how* you do that).

Answer (score 0):

There's an ultra helpful function I learned recently jQuery has with AJAX that might be of use to you.

```
var states;
$.get('states.json', function(data) {
    states=data;
    alert(data);
    alert(states);
}, "text").done(function(result) {console.log(result);};
```

That should print out the states. 
Check out the API for AJAX here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/